# display error collapse accordion bootstrap

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I do a file explorer with symfony2 and Php 5.3 :)

I wanna display  {{ Twig error }} when a directory is empty . Here my twig view :

```
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href=".mycollapse3">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right"></i> Tableaux de bord mensuels
    </a>
</div>
{% for tab in tableauxliste %}
    <div class="accordion-group">
        {% if tableauxliste is empty %}
        <div class="mycollapse3 collapse alert alert-info">
            {{ erreur }}
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-heading mycollapse3 collapse">
            <ul>
                <a data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapse3{{ tab[0] }}">
                    {{ tab[0] }}
                </a>
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3{{ tab[0] }}" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                {% if tab[0] is empty %}
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        {{ erreur }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {% for file in tab[1] %}
                    {% set repertoire = dir_tableaudebord ~ '/' ~ tab[0] %}
                    <ul><a target="_blank" href="{{ path('affiche', { 'repertoire':repertoire, 'file':file }) }}"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> {{ file | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252') }}</a></ul>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In this case, the error isn't hidden and I don't know why.

I just wanna hide the error and display it after click on it.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add to you action some condition and return response (render this data's in template).

```
return $this->render(
   'FolderBundle:To/you:template.html.twig',
        [
           'erreur' => $erreur
           'tableauxliste' => $tableauxliste,
        ]
);
```

And use this variable in you template.

Comment: Done. the problem is that if $tableauxliste is empty , the error is displayed before clicking..